# Sign-in Provider Issue While Using Third Party Auth With Firebase v3.3.0

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a puzzling issue with third party (Twitter) sign-in to my Firebase instance. I get the following exception when trying to authenticate via *signInWithPopup* JavaScript method:

```
The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.
```

I have confirmed that Twitter sign-in is indeed **enabled** in the Firebase console:[image]

I have read various blog posts stating that Firebase users have experienced issues with third party auth when using **v2.x.x** of the Firebase SDK when having their projects created in the new console (subdomain of Google). However, I don't think these conditions are applicable to my situation because:

- My Node project is using Firebase **v3.3.0** npm package and I haven't found anyone else complaining about third party auth while using this version.
- I created my Firebase project using the new console.

Other things that may be useful to know:

- I can read/write data from/to Firebase without any problems
- I have not tried any other authentication methods

Great thanks to whoever can shed some light on this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this issue by creating a new Firebase instance in the old console and then porting it over to the new console. My only assumption is that the authentication problems noticed with v2.x.x versions haven't been fixed with v3.x.x :(